# Ruby on Rails 3 Documentation: "Can I" \ "Is it advisable" use (at least) a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, nested

I read [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), in particular the section [2.7 Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) \ 2.7.1 Limits to Nesting where it says

> Resources should never be nested more
>   than 1 level deep.

**What does it mean? That is, "can I" \ "is it advisable" use one level nested resource like this**

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :publishers do
    resources :magazines
  end
end
```

**or I should use something like this**

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :publishers
  resources :magazines
end
```

**?** What do you think about?

If it is a recommended approach, how to write route paths (for example `new_users_publisher_magazine`...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shallow routes for resources as well. This follows the best of both worlds. It automatically nests resources one level deep even if you nest them multiple levels in your code.

```
namespace :users do
  shallow do
    resources :publishers do
      resources :maagazines
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need.

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :publishers do
    resources :magazines
  end
end
```

will give you different routes than

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :publishers
  resources :magazines
end
```

For one thing, the second one gives you routes like

/users/1/publishers/ and /users/1/magazines

while the first one gives

/users/1/publishers/1/magazines

It is recommended not to nest that much into your routes as much as possible unless you REALLY REALLY need to, like your life depended on it :P. That's just what i think though, because a nest of 3 levels will probably make you suffer more than it will help you.

Comment: the first code you put is what you need. namespace "users" do
  resources :publishers do
    resources :magazines
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

I think it's matter of taste. It's just a guide not a rule. If you feel better with first approach then go for it. I use double nested resources and nobody from my coworkers doesn't complaint about it. But of course If I would see 4 or more levels of nested resources it would be just hard to write paths, so limit for me is two (sometimes 3). You should choose your own limit.

Answer (score 0):

It says more than one level so this is right and recommended as far as you will always will access a  magazine through a publisher:

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :publishers do
    resources :magazines
  end
end
```

Comment: As I said you will have to write the route to a magazine always from a publisher, thus: `/users/publisher/5/magazines`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the models: if a magazine belongs to a publisher and a publisher belongs to a user, then the two-level nesting would make sense (though it's not really necessary). If a publisher has many users, then I would advise against this approach since it will make things unnecessarily complicated.

To view the named route helpers for your resources you can use 'rake routes'. It gives a nice overview of the defined routes.